# How to rename a file extension with NetBeans?

Tags: file, maven, netbeans, directory, rename

I'm use NetBeans 8 for my new Maven Java Web project.
The code generation really helps.

***But, how Am I supposed to rename the extension of a file?***

```
hello.jsp --> hello.xhtml
```

*NetBeans "rename" only allow to change the first part, not the extension.* Do I really have to go to my system-folder and change the file there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to edit the properties. Right click on the file -> Properties.

A dialog will open where you can change the extension and more.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Netbeans 8.0.2 to change a .html file to .jsp. When I right click and select properties I get a properties list with all kinds of html tags but no option to rename the file.

Comment: I cannot believe NetBeans 8.2 implemented a means of changing file extensions through the properties dialog but for some INSANE reason this doesn't work with html files? Nevermind the fact that it shouldn't even be this hard to change file extensions... I should take a look and see just how convoluted their filesystem works to make changing file-extensions that tedious.

Comment: See response of KraftART Berlin below: when it concerns an html file, it must not be opened in the editor in order to change the extension.

Comment: @dschoorl: Thanks, closing the file allowed me to change the file ext.

Comment: In 8.2 version, I could change extension without going to file view. I had to right click on require file name, go to Properties and change value of property Extention!

Answer (score 4):

you can't change the fileExtension with rightClick, when the file is open! close the editTab and then u can change the extension.

When the file is open, u get with rightClick/Properties other options!

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file outside of Netbeans using a file browser for your OS and the extension will automatically change in Netbeans.

When you install the [Files In Explorer](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57153/files-in-explorer) plugin for Netbeans you can quickly open the folder from within Netbeans by right clicking the folder and selecting "Open in System Browser". From there you can rename the file extension.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, you can't change the extension. In NetBeans you create an object and work with that; there's no method to convert that into another type of object.

To solve your problem, you can create a new hello.xhtml object and copy the code. Or change the extension on the file system, outside of NetBeans.

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to provide a desired extension when you save a copy of an already opened file. Afterwards you can delete the file with the wrong extension.